# why jquery on() function does not work with id or class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have two menus in same page, I'm changing the menu's icon `on('shown')` event. jQuery function is working fine with first `html` but it does not working with second one (same html).

### HTML

```
<button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle  repnsive-navbar-toggle">
    <div id="navbar-hamburger">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar-close" class="hidden">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </div>
</button>
```

### JS

```
$(function() {
  $('#navbarCollapse')
    .on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
      $('#navbar-hamburger').addClass('hidden');
      $('#navbar-close').removeClass('hidden');    
    })
    .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
      $('#navbar-hamburger').removeClass('hidden');
      $('#navbar-close').addClass('hidden');        
    });
});
```

I tried to handle this issue using `class` and `id` in this `$('#navbarCollapse')`. But second menu does not working. Is there possible that I add class or id for second menu instead of changing the `data-target="#navbarCollapse"`.

Comment: create a fiddle mate

Comment: $('#navbarCollapse') will select an element with an attribute id="navbarCollapse". If you want to select the button in your html, you should use the selector $('[data-target="#navbarCollapse"]').

Comment: @LexLustor I add new attribute `data-id` in `button` tag and use this as, but still does not working, `$('[data-id="#navButtonToggle"]')`

Comment: @PhpDeveloper So the problem doesn't reside in the selector but in your overall markup. Can you provide a jsfiddle or expand you question with more of your html?